# What is this error when I run SHAP ? "cannot import name '_validate_lengths'"

Tags: python, shap

When I run `import shap` I'm getting below error:

```
import shap
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-efbb001a1501>", line 1, in <module>
    import shap

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .plots.summary import summary_plot

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\summary.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import colors

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\colors.py", line 7, in <module>
    import skimage.color

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from .util.dtype import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .arraycrop import crop

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\arraycrop.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.lib.arraypad import _validate_lengths

ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_lengths'
```